# Show time series data with primeng

Tags: angular, primeng, linechart

I want to plot a time series data (on a line chart), similar to this:

```
[
   {year: 2008, value: 0.07686},
   {year: 2008, value: 0.08636},
   {year: 2009, value: 0.096889},
   {year: 2009, value: 0.01234},
   {year: 2010, value: 0.06686},
   ....
]
```

Where the year will go along `x-axis` and value on `y-axis`. The documentation only discusses about defining the labels on x and the respective values along y. Would defining a single label, `2008` in this case, along with its `dataset: 0.07686, 0.08636`  work? Is it supported by the framework?

Comment: can you give line to documentation you looking at?

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/chart here you go..

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if it consider "work" for you, but you can do something like this:

```
constructor() {
  let other = [
    {year: 2008, value: 0.07686},
    {year: 2008, value: 0.08636},
    {year: 2009, value: 0.096889},
    {year: 2009, value: 0.01234},
    {year: 2010, value: 0.06686},      
  ]


  this.data = {
          labels: other.map(y=>y.year),
          datasets: [
              {
                  label: 'First Dataset',
                  data: other.map(y=>y.value)
              }
          ]
      }
  }
```

look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-stackoverflow-answer?file=app/app.component.ts)